# Nextjs 13 using prisma in api route

Tags: typescript, postgresql, prisma, next.js13

Trying to make a register route in my api. I have my api route file to create a user in my database, and everything seems to be working except for my prisma queries. I've tried commenting out the prisma queries and putting console logs everywhere and can confirm that the issues are coming from somewhere in the prisma queries

```
  const res = await request.json()
  console.log(res)
  const { SECRET } = process.env;

  const createToken = (username: string, id: number) => {
    return jwt.sign({ username, id }, SECRET, { expiresIn: "2 days" });
  };
  console.log('i still work 1.5')
  try {
    //@ts-ignore
    const { username, password }: { username: string; password: string } =
      res;
    const foundUser = await prisma.user.findFirst({
      where: { username: username },
    });
    await prisma.$disconnect()
    console.log('i still work 2')
    if (foundUser) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        {
          message: "cannot create user",
        },
        {
          status: 400,
        }
      );
    } else {
      console.log('i still work 3')
      const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
      const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
      const newUser: any = await prisma.user.create({
        data: {
          username: username,
          hashedPass: hash,
          createdAt: new Date(),
          updatedAt: new Date(),
        },
      });
      await prisma.$disconnect()

      console.log(newUser)
      
      const token = createToken(newUser.username, newUser.id);
      const exp = Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 48;
      return NextResponse.json(
        {
          username: newUser.dataValues.username,
          id: newUser.dataValues.id,
          token,
          exp,
        },
        {
          status: 200,
        }
      );
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        message: err,
        info: 'hello'
      },
      {
        status: 400,
      }
    );
  }
}
```

My models:

```
model Book {
  id         Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  title      String?      @db.VarChar(255)
  summary    String?
  createdAt  DateTime     @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updatedAt  DateTime     @db.Timestamptz(6)
  userId     Int?
  users      User?       @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  chapters   Chapter[]
  characters Character[]
}

model Chapter {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  num       Int?
  name      String?  @db.VarChar(255)
  outline   String?
  createdAt DateTime @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updatedAt DateTime @db.Timestamptz(6)
  bookId    Int?
  books     Book?   @relation(fields: [bookId], references: [id])
}

model Character {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String?  @db.VarChar(255)
  role        String?  @db.VarChar(255)
  description String?
  createdAt   DateTime @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updatedAt   DateTime @db.Timestamptz(6)
  bookId      Int?
  books       Book?   @relation(fields: [bookId], references: [id])
}

model User {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  username   String?  @db.VarChar(255)
  hashedPass String?  @db.VarChar(255)
  createdAt  DateTime @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updatedAt  DateTime @db.Timestamptz(6)
  books      Book[]
}
```

Comment: what errors are you getting? this needs more context

Comment: I'd love to provide more context but all the error says in the message is {clientVersion: '4.14.0'} which is the version of primsa/client that i have

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.